# How to save multiple file upload in a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, upload, google-forms, multiple-file-upload

I have created a custom form on Google Form which contains an Upload File Question (allowing multiple files). I'm trying to run a script when submitting the form that creates a folder into a specific destination in Drive and that it saves the files uploaded in this one. But I have no idea how to retrieve the ID of the files uploaded and move them into the new folder.
Thank you

I managed to create the new folder, but I'm not able to select the uploaded file and save them (or move them) to the target folder. I'm not posting the creating folder code.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[1];
  var uploadedfile = itemResponse.getResponse();

  //now??
}
```

I would like to get the ID of the file but using the .getItem().getID() method I get something like 1.148501776E9
Also how can I loop through the uploaded files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When the files are uploaded by Google form, you want to move the uploaded files to the specific folder.
- You have already installed the OnSubmit event trigger for `onFormSubmit()`.
- You have already had the folder ID of the destination folder.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- [`.getItem().getId()` is the item's unique identifier.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#getid)
- `getResponse()` of `itemResponses` has the file IDs of uploaded files. You can use this.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the destination folder ID to `var folderId = "###"`.

**When you modified the script, please delete the OnSubmit event trigger once and install the trigger again. At that time, if the authorization screen is displayed. Please authorize it. By this, the script works.** Please be careful this.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // I modified below script.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  var folderId = "###";  // Please set folder ID of the destination folder.

  var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      var ids = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[j]);
        destfolder.addFile(file);
        file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In my test case, when `Utilities.sleep(3000)` is not used, there was the case that an error occurs because the file is tried to move before the upload of file is not finished. So I put it. If in your environment, no error occurs without it, please remove it.

#### References:

- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [addFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addfilechild)
- [removeFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefilechild)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was perfect. I didn't use the sleep function since it seems working without it

Comment: @E. Tocchi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hello, I was searching for a solution for this problem and happen to find this page. I have copied the codes and have updated the folder ID. But when I submit it, it does not run the function. Is there a place where I have to call the function?

Comment: @Kyle I would like to support you. But from `I have copied the codes and have updated the folder ID. But when I submit it, it does not run the function. Is there a place where I have to call the function?`, I cannot understand your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post your current issue as new question by including the detail information for replicating your issue? I think that by this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Google stores the uploaded files in the following way:

1. It creates a folder `"Placeholder_for_Name_of_the_Form"(File responses)` and subfolder: `"Placeholder_for_Name_of_Question"(File responses)` and stores all uploaded files there.
2. If you link the form to a spreadsheet, the spreadsheet will contain the URL to the uploaded file (which contains the ID) as an answer to the question. You can access these data also programmatically with Apps Script (relevant methods: `openSpreadsheetbyId()`; `getRage()`; `getValues()`,...).

[image]

This information could be useful for you if you want to retrieve the data at a different time point than `onFormSubmit()`.