# Google Form: How to move all files uploaded to a specific folder on submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Firstly I apologise for my lack of knowledge here - no doubt this is fairly simple for someone that understands this -

I'm trying to have all files uploaded for each form submitted placed in a single folder.

I have this code which I found here: [Google Form: How to save multiple file upload in a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952300/google-form-how-to-save-multiple-file-upload-in-a-specific-folder)

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // I modified below script.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  var folderId = "###";  // Please set folder ID of the destination folder.

  var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      var ids = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[j]);
        destfolder.addFile(file);
        file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On submit, it gives this error "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 12, file "Code")"

Line 12 being this:

```
  var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
```

Two questions:
- What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

- What should I be placing in the destination folder ID?
  I'd like to do the same thing i'm doing with Form Publisher which acmes the output PDF as follows, based on the detail in the form submitted: <> - <> - <>

Comment: When the folder ID, which cannot be accessed and/or is not existed is used to `###` of `var folderId = "###";`, such error occurs. So can I ask you whether you set the folder ID you can access to `###` of `var folderId = "###";`?

Comment: According to the error you are getting, your script does not have access to the folder you want to insert your files to. Are you sure you can access that folder? Are you sure the script being executed by your account? Of course, if you have not done so, you should change `###` of `var folderId = "###";` to your destination folder id. Check [this](https://ploi.io/documentation/mysql/where-do-i-get-google-drive-folder-id) if you don't know how to get the ID of a Drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ft=e.values.slice(1);//This is where are the file url were located
  var fA=ft[0].split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fA[i].slice(fA[i].indexOf("=")+1));
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": "FolderId"}]}, file.getId());
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
  } 
}
```